# Как использовать функцию в функции?

Tags: javascript

Решил создать программку-тест в которой проверяется результат умножения для двух случайных чисел. Пользователь в поле ввода записывает результат, а программа через **10** вопросов должна вернуть статистику. Вот мой код:

```js
function main() {

  var numb1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 9); // Вот эти строчки кода занести в функцию
  var numb2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
  var result = numb1 * numb2;

  var rate = 0;
  var counter = 0;

  var input = document.getElementById("text");
  var str = document.createElement('span');
  str.innerHTML = numb1 + " x " + numb2 + " ="; //И эти
  input.before(str);

  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = "Calculate";
  document.body.append(button);

  button.onclick = function() {
    if (mainForm.text.value == result) {
      rate++;
      counter++;
    } else {
      counter++;
    }

    if (counter == 10) {
      var str1 = document.getElementById("firstSpan");
      str1.style.display = "block";
      str1.innerHTML = "Rate:" + rate * 10 + "%";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("firstSpan").style.display = "none";
    }

    if (counter == 10) {
      var str2 = document.getElementById("secondSpan");
      str2.style.display = "block";
      str2.innerHTML = " " + rate + " correct answers from 10";
      rate = 0;
      counter = 0;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("secondSpan").style.display = "none"
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="main()">
  <span id="firstSpan"></span>
  <span id="secondSpan"></span>
  <form id="mainForm">
    <input type="text" id="text">
  </form>
</body>
```

Программа работает корректно, но осталось только понять, как постоянно менять числа, т.к сейчас остаются одни и те же. Я понимаю, почему это так работает и придумал решение, но не знаю, как это сделать технически.

Суть моего решения: те строчки кода, где генерируется случайные числа и те строчки кода, где эти  числа выводятся в документ, вот фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно вынести в отдельную функцию и вызывать её нажатием кнопки, но я не знаю как.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как можно вынести в отдельную функцию.

```js
function main() {

  var numb1 = 0
  var numb2 = 0
  var result = 0;

  var rate = 0;
  var counter = 0;

  var input = document.getElementById("text");
  var str = document.createElement('span');

  input.before(str);

  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = "Calculate";
  document.body.append(button);

  function generateExample() {
    numb1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 9); // Вот эти строчки кода занести в функцию
    numb2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
    result = numb1 * numb2;
    str.innerHTML = numb1 + " x " + numb2 + " ="; //И эти
    input.value = '';
  }

  generateExample();

  button.onclick = function() {
    if (mainForm.text.value == result) {
      rate++;
      counter++;
    } else {
      counter++;
    }

    if (counter == 10) {
      var str1 = document.getElementById("firstSpan");
      str1.style.display = "block";
      str1.innerHTML = "Rate:" + rate * 10 + "%";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("firstSpan").style.display = "none";
    }

    if (counter == 10) {
      var str2 = document.getElementById("secondSpan");
      str2.style.display = "block";
      str2.innerHTML = " " + rate + " correct answers from 10";
      rate = 0;
      counter = 0;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("secondSpan").style.display = "none"
    }
    generateExample();
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="main()">
  <span id="firstSpan"></span>
  <span id="secondSpan"></span>
  <form id="mainForm">
    <input type="text" id="text">
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);

function main() {  
  let answers = {
    correct: 0,
    total: 0,
  };
  
  let answer = id("answer");  
  let message = id("message");
  
  let example = create_example();

  id("btn").addEventListener("click", submit);
  // Передается "имя" функции, которую нужно вызвать при клике
  
  answer.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if (e.key == "Enter") submit(); // вызывается "вручную", через скобки()
    // Лень кликать на кнопку, пусть срабатывает и при нажатии Enter
  });

  /***/
  function submit() {
    if (answer.value == example.result) answers.correct++; // (*1)

    (++answers.total == 10) ? (show_message(), reset_answers()) : hide_message(); // (*2)

    example = create_example();
    answer.value = "";
  }
  
  /*** Вызываются из submit() */
  function show_message() {
    let rate = answers.correct / answers.total; 
    
    message.innerHTML = `
      Rate: ${ rate * 100 }% <br>
      ${ answers.correct } correct answers from 10
    `;
    
    message.style.display = "block";
  }

  function hide_message() {
    message.style.display = "none";
  }

  function reset_answers() {
    answers.correct = answers.total = 0;
  }

  function create_example() {
    let a = Math.random() * 10 | 0;
    let b = Math.random() * 10 | 0;

    id("math-example").textContent = `${a} * ${b} =`;
    answer.focus(); // Пусть фокус сразу стоит на поле при каждой новой задаче
    
    return {
      result: a * b,
    };
  }  
  
  /***/
  function id(str) { // мелкая обертка, лень везде писать document.getElementById
    return document.getElementById(str);
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="math-example"></span>
<input id="answer">
<hr>
<button id="btn">Submit</button>

<p id="message"></p>
```

**(*1)** `if (answer.value == example.result) answers.correct++;`

Нужно понимать, что `answer.value` — строка, `example.result` - число. При нестрогом сравнении, строка неявно приводится к числовому типу. А если например ничего не введут, а правильный result — 0, сравнение `"" == 0` выдаст true. При необходимости надо бы добавить валидацию ответа)

**(*2)** `(++answers.total == 10) ? (show_message(), reset_answers()) : hide_message();`

Менее выпендрежный аналог:

```
answers.total++;

if (answers.total == 10) {
  show_message();
  reset_answers();
} else {
  hide_message();
}
```

P.s. `var numb1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);` — Это проблема, и вот почему:

```js
let arr = new Array(10).fill(0);

for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  let index = Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
  arr[index]++;
}

console.log( Object.entries(arr).join("\n") );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100vh; }
```

Выпадают числа в интервале [0, 9), числа от 0 до 0.5 округляются до нуля, числа от 8.5 до 9 → до девяти. В итоге 0 и 9 выпадают вдвое реже, чем остальные. Поэтому эти строчки заменил на `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);`

Answer (score 0):

После некоторого времени разбирательств и чтения документация я понял, что разобраться с функцией я не могу, поэтому придумал другой способ. Я удалял строку с помощью метода `remove`:

```
 var clearStr = document.getElementById('str');
 clearStr.remove(str);
 var clearButton = document.getElementById('button');
 clearButton.remove(button);
 main();
 mainForm.text.value = "";
```

Хоть и не разобрался с функциями, но сделал сам, может быть кому-то когда-то это пригодится!